# Magic hidden make file variables. Where are they documented?

Tags: makefile

I am looking at a couple of UNIX software source make files. They appear to be using variables that are not defined by make, and not explicitly by the author of the make file either. For instance in one there is DESTDIR, in another INSTALL_ROOT. I know what these do but I don't where they are documented, how they came about, if they are standardized, or what other such implicit/hidden dependencies make files can have on such variables by convention or otherwise. So my question is where are these types of variables documented and what other meaningful variables like these exist?

Comment: Perhaps they're environment variables?

Comment: Well you could pass them in to make from the environment. Maybe they are documented with the UNIX environment?? I don't know, will have to look deeper!

Comment: [DESTDIR](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html)

Answer (score 1):

These makefile conventions, as far as GNU is concerned are described at https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html#Makefile-Conventions. Thank you @Banther. I did not Google thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those variables is 'standard' in either `make` or the Unix environment generally.  That they're used in a makefile without being defined suggests that there is either some context missing for the makefile or (more likely) the makefile isn't very good.

The two names are, however, at least similar to names that are often used.  They usually mean much the same thing.

The `INSTALL_ROOT` implies that instead of using `/` as the top-level directory for the installation, the install code should use the named directory — perhaps `/usr/local` instead.  Binaries will be installed in `${INSTALL_ROOT}/bin`; headers will go in `${INSTALL_ROOT}/include`; libraries in `${INSTALL_ROOT}/lib`; manual pages in `${INSTALL_DIR}/man/manN` for different sections of the manual; etc.

Using `DESTDIR` might mean that only the binary needs to be installed, so it maps to `/usr/local/bin` or something similar.  Or it might be a synonym for `INSTALL_ROOT` meaning that the software will be installed in suitable subdirectories under `${DESTDIR}`.  (`make` supports both `${VARIABLE}` and `$(VARIABLE)` to expand a variable.)

If you're required to set them, the `README` file or `INSTALL` file should contain the information about how and why to set them.  For example, you might write:

```
make INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local
```

on the command line that invokes `make`, though it is a little unusual to make people do that — there should be a default which is suitable for as many people as possible.  Often, if the auto-configuration system is used, the directory is specified via:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local
```

(since the default is `/usr/local` when using the auto-configuration tools).

Comment: Yeah DESTDIR and INSTALL_ROOT are synonyms. I was more wanting to know what other variables like this exist. The link @Banthar posted seem to give an authoritative answer for GNU anyway.

Comment: OK.  The answer is that for any given system, there may be a myriad of other related variables.  There are semi-standard names thanks to the standards laid down by GNU, but there are (as ever) competing standards (Perl, X11 do things at least somewhat differently — and have their own peculiarities).